# Script Alert não funciona

Tags: php, javascript, aplicação-web

Possuo um código de upload de arquivos funcionando perfeitamente, porém o alert na condição else não está funcionando apenas o alert do IF.

**Segue o código:**

```
if(isset($_FILES['allfiles'])){//verifica o input file, caso estiver setado irá preparar as variaveis e caso o arquivo seja maior que 15mb irá mostrar erro.
   $errors= array();
   $file_name = $_FILES['allfiles']['name'];
   $namefile = $_POST ['allfiles'];
   $file_size = $_FILES['allfiles']['size'];
   $file_tmp = $_FILES['allfiles']['tmp_name'];
   $file_type= $_FILES['allfiles']['type'];
   $ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   $pasta1 = $_POST ['pasta1'];
   $pasta2 = $_POST ['pasta2'];
   if($file_size > 15097152){
      $errors[]='O arquivo nao pode exceder 15mb';
   } 


   if(empty($errors)==true){//caso não haja erro irá mover o arquivo para o diretório selecionado.
    if (empty ($namefile)==true){
        if (empty ($pasta1)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"pasta/".$ID."/pasta1/".$file_name);
        }
        if (empty ($pasta2) ==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"pasta/".$ID."/pasta2/".$file_name);
        }
    }
    if (empty ($namefile)==false){
        if (empty ($pasta1)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"pasta/".$ID."/pasta1/".$file_name);
            rename ("pasta/".$ID."/pasta1/".$file_name, "pasta/".$ID."/pasta1/".$namefile.".".$ext);
        }
        if (empty ($pasta2) ==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"pasta/".$ID."/pasta2/".$file_name);
            rename ("pasta/".$ID."/pasta2/".$file_name, "pasta/".$ID."/pasta2/".$namefile.".".$ext);
        }
    }
   echo "<script>alert('Arquivo enviado com sucesso!')</script>";
   }else{
   echo "<script>alert('Arquivo deve ser menor que 15mb!')</script>";
   }
}
```

**OBS** : Já verifiquei se o problema era a variável $errors porém mesmo colocando no IF do $file_size ainda sim continua não funcionando, acredito que esteja ocorrendo algum conflito no php. Já testei o código em outra página em branco e ainda não funcionou, a única coisa que acontece quando tento fazer upload de um arquivo maior que 15mb é um reload na página, que até agora não estou entendendo pois não tenho nenhuma referência a um refresh no código.
Alguém possui alguma idéia do que poderia estar causando esse problema?

Comment: Não ficou claro o problema, principalmente quando diz que "*está funcionando perfeitamente, mas não funciona*". Você aparentemente possui dois alertas: um no `if`, outro no `else`. O alerta do `if` funciona, mas do `else` não? Você tem ciência que apenas um será executado por vez, certo? Se sim, em que situação exatamente não funciona? E pode melhorar a indentação do código? Está bem difícil entender quando um `if` começa e termina...

Comment: Exatamente. O alert do else não funciona, esse else pertence ao IF no qual a condição é a variável $errors vazia, onde ela só recebe um valor caso o arquivo seja maior que 15 mb, o upload do arquivo não ocorre também o que está certo, porém gostaria que aparecesse um aviso de que isso não ocorreu e não estou conseguindo resolver isso de forma alguma.

Comment: Insere um echo "teste";exit; no seu else e veja se ele aparece. As vezes o problema não é o alert, talvez ele não esteja entrando no else.

Comment: não retornou nada também. mas o problema não está no else exatamente e sim em alguma outra coisa pois havia colocado o script dentro do if($file_size > 15097152){      } e também não funcionou, acredito que tenha alguma coisa relacionada a tentativa de upload de arquivos grandes. talvez um sobrecarregamento?

Comment: Veja no seu php.ini como está o tamanho limite do corpo de uma requisição, deve está menor que 15mb, aí ele nem chega a executar o código. São as opções **post_max_size** e
**upload_max_filesize**

Comment: mudei ambos para 50 e agora sequer consigo carregar a página, teria algum valor ideal para colocar?

Comment: Qual valor estava antes? O valor padrão é 20M. É preciso reiniciar o servidor também para fazer efeito.

Comment: sim, após reiniciar o servidor não consegui mais. vou testar com 20

Comment: Agora o servidor sequer está iniciando, não estou vendo sentido, coloquei o post_max_size=20 e o upload_max_filesize=20M

Comment: fiz um reboot e agora voltou no problema de não carregar a página.

Comment: Resolvido, com a adição do M no post_max_size=20M

Comment: Problema resolvido, se puder responder a pergunta para finalizar o post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando ocorre da página nem carregar após o upload de um arquivo muito grande, é preciso checar se o limite do corpo da requisição POST e o limite do tamanho do arquivo para upload no PHP não está muito baixo. É possível checar esses valores no arquivo php.ini:

**post_max_size**: [http://php.net/post-max-size](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
post_max_size = 20M
```

**upload_max_filesize**: [http://php.net/upload-max-filesize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 20M
```

Lembrando que é preciso colocar o "M" de megabytes, senão os valores vão ser lidos como bytes. Também é preciso notar que o **post_max_size** nunca deve ser menor que o **upload_max_filesize**, e se você pretende enviar mais de um arquivo por vez, por exemplo, 3 arquivos de 20mb, o post_max_size precisaria ser 60mb.